# Best approach to create a WCF keep-alive mechanism

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api2

I'm a .NET back-end developer, working on a project which includes a website platform.

One of the requirements is to have payment process. For this process I must have some kind of a calculator service.

To calculate the payment for each of the clients depending on some criteria stored in the database.

The technologies I'm using:

1. ASP.NET Web API 2
2. SQL Server
3. Windows Services/Console Application for the back-end logic

This calculator service should be available for all of the parts written above.
Which means when a client is on the website and asks for a payment, WebApi has access to this payment process, when the back-end logic need the calculation the same happen and so on..

I'm not sure if I took the best approach however I created a simple WCF service 
using HTTP binding for this solution.

However I have some doubts about it since WCF is not always reliable, if it is down I need to do some kind of a check to see if the process is alive.

So I have 2 questions:

- Is the WCF service a correct choice for my approach? Is there any better approach ?
- If the WCF Service is the correct choice is there a way to create a keep-alive mechanism in WebAPI?

Comment: Why would you use a WCF Service? Can't you query the database from the Website itself? Do you need the calculator for other services?

Comment: Next to your comment in regards to WCF Service is not always reliable. Why do you think it is not reliable?

Comment: Yes i do , im trying to avoid putting logic in the database , other then that i dont want every time a payment process is done to get to the database for the criterias, i prefer to get all the data to some kind of a service and then make this service availible for any other process/webapi and so on..

Comment: Maybe reliable is not the correct word,
I mean that WCF alone is not very good for me cause i need to implment some kind of a Thread that will check if the WCF service is availible since this payment process is major and important part of the system.

Comment: There is a difference between putting logic in to your database and retrieving data from your database and use the data within a Business Logic layer in your Website.

Comment: If you just don't want to rewrite code, why don't you just put the code into a library then, which you include in your other projects? I still don't understand why you need the WCF service at all.

Comment: This is the reason i had this question , In the beggining i wanted just to create a library , however the way this service getting the creiteria to calculate should be change in a daily basis by the admin of this site,
The data will be saved in db tables , the service once in a while should refresh its data from the database , as i figured it is going to be a little complicated i decided to have its own service,
And its not just solve the rewrite code part , the data should always be the same for every process using this

Comment: if i did a class library it means that in every change i would need to update the DLLs in all of my system. this will be high maintanance since its new and would require a lot of changes in the next few months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information supplied and the answers given in the comments there is no use to use a WebAPI to calculate any data.

From my point you need to add an project that does the calculation process. This includes retrieving data from your database and calculates the data based on the information supplied by your website. This project returns the calculated data to your website.

No need for Webservices, Windows Services or console applications.

For your admin you create a 2nd project that maintains the database and include the same project.

Comment: Sorry but you got it wrong , webapi is one of the consumers of the calculating service. Im using webapi just to connect with this calculator service and to retrive calculation data.

Comment: You have a Website that queries another one. That approach is more expensive compared to querying the database by another project which contains the calculation module. The only reason why you would do that is when it comes to security layers and governance. 
Please tell me how your infrastructure looks like. From my point of view it is over kill in the process.

Comment: I think you are right, Thanks for the answers , i think i have better approch which i dont need a different service for this.. i felt that something was not right here with this WCF service.